# Creating QGIS Print Composer map templates?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, references, template

The company I work for has asked me to create a number of templates for the different maps we include in our reports. What would be the best way of creating templates (logo, scale bar, legend).

Is there any resource (youtube or guide) you can suggest?

Answer (score 9):

You can easily save map templates from print composer, [see documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/print_composer.html#print-composer).

1. Create a map composer

   In your project go *Project --> New Print Composer* and set a name for map composer. You can also use *Composer Manager* for this step
2. Prepare your map output in composer

   Add title, map windows, legends and set desired parametres for this items
3. Saving as a template

   In print composer window click *Composer --> Save as Template...*
4. Using a template

   In main QGIS window (project) open composer manager *Project --> Composer Manager...*. In *New from template* option select *Specific* and select your saved template.

In composer manager window you can load your templates, creating new or duplicate previously created composers in project.